# How to make image/buttons stay in place when re-sizing web browser

Tags: html, css

This is my image-button for my website. http://puu.sh/cK7Sf/6309c39cdb.jpg When I re-size my browser it goes over here http://puu.sh/cK7VU/f17dafcc41.jpg

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="Nav">
    <div id="buttons">
        <a href="/"><div id="home_button"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#home_button {
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 196px;
left: 502px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `left: 502px;`

You should center `div id="buttons"`, for example like this:

```
.Nav {
display: flex;
}
#buttons {
margin: 0 auto;
}
#home_button {
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
}
```

This will center `#buttons` inside `.Nav` and `#home_button` would be on the left

Comment: its not left, its centered. i can only get it to move up.

Answer (score 0):

To have a dynamic website, you need to have flowing elements, not absolute elements.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute
In this link you will see that the heading is fixed to the location because it is positioned absolute.

For a flowing element, as you want. Try this;

html - replace all 'a' within your buttons div with li's (As it is a list)

```
<ul>
    <li id='HomeButton'><a href='#'></a></li> <!-- Duplicate this line with as many links as you want -->
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#buttons ul {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
#buttons li {
    float: left;
}
#HomeButton {
    background: url("home.png") no-repeat;
    backgroound-size: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Also:
To make your code more efficient and cleaner to read, head to this link and view the bottom section 'Background shorthand' http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp - Shorthand coding is faster for both typing and reading.

eg.

```
background-image: x
background-repeat: x
```

is slower than 
    background: url("home.png") no-repeat;